# Java, creating a JComboBox and add to year range

Tags: java, swing

No programming errors but more of a question, I want to display years from 1930s to 2016 in a JComboBox so the user can select their year of birth, what is the best approach for this because I do not want to separately add 60 selections in the combobox or is that the only approach?

Comment: The most user friendly way would be to let the user type his year of birth into a JTextField.  If you're going to use Ashan アシャン's answer, reverse the for loop so that 2016 is first and 1930 is last.  Unless you're letting babies use your GUI, set the youngest year of birth based on something more age appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't no this is best way to this. but you can done your task like this,

```
 JComboBox jComboBox1=new JComboBox();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();   
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
        Vector v=new Vector();
        for (int i = 1930; i <= year; i++) {
            v.add(i);
        }
        jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v));
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(year);
```